# Migrating schema and SP from informix to mysql

Tags: mysql, informix

We need to redo a database in MySQL that has been already done on Informix, is there a way to migrate not only the schema, but the stored procedures as well?

Thanks.

We have a client whom we built a web application that uses an Informix database. Now the client wants to be able to implement the same software but on multiple closed networks (like 20). Doing this using Informix would be very expensive (20 licences X_X).

So the best approach is to redo the database on something like MySQL.

The application was done using Flex, .Net (using ODBC) and Informix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done a similar thing, but I migrated Informix database to PostgreSQL. At first I dbexported the whole database, so the whole data and schema info was in text. Then I wrote some Python programs that translated schema, for example Informix `DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND` must be converted to `timestamp with time zone`.

When all `CREATE TABLE/INDEX` etc worked then I translated `.unl` files to PostgreSQL `COPY` commands. You should search how to do bulk load in MySQL, or convert those files to `INSERT` commands.

After that I started converting stored procedures. While PostgreSQL PL/pgSQL and Informix SPL are very different this part was the hardest and I was able to automatically convert only function "prototypes". Functions body had to be converted manually.

If you completed this you will have to check if your application work well with a new SQL implementation.

Comment: how hard was it for you and/or your team to translate from SPL to PL? do you feel you basically redid your SP or was it easier since you just manually translated your code? Im trying to estimate time, thanks

Comment: I think you must check how many stored procedures you have and what they do, then translate some of them. If you translate from 3 to 5 it would be easier to say how much time you will have to spend to translate all procedures.